ModelStructurePanel outside the viewer container
I would like to move the modelStructurePanel outside of the viewer container and into my custom sidebar. As stated in another post this is not recommended since it requires extra fixing of the css so that the content of the panel is displayed correctly. I think this is where my problem lies. My modelStructurePanel element is displayed in my custom sidebar only as a small text that reads 'browser'.
In my html I added an element called 'modelBrowserContent' where the panel should go. For this I used the following Code:
const modelStructurePanel = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ModelStructurePanel(
        document.getElementById('modelBrowserContent'),
        'modelStructurePanel',
        'Model Structure',
        {}
    );
    modelStructurePanel.setVisible(true);

This is how the element is displayed
Does anyone know how to fix this so that the panel is actually showing the models tree-structure?
According to the other post some CSS is needed but I did not manage to display the tree.

The approach to address this is by taking advantage of the data from the model and building your UI outside of Viewer.
I built a quick sample that you can check at https://github.com/JoaoMartins-callmeJohn/aps-viewer-external-tree
You can also find a live demo at https://joaomartins-callmejohn.github.io/aps-viewer-external-tree/
And the code for that extension is available below:
class ExternalTreeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  constructor(viewer, options) {
    super(viewer, options);
    this._onObjectTreeCreated = (ev) => this.onModelLoaded(ev.model);
    this.treeContainer = "#tree";
    this.tree = null;
  }

  async load() {
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, this._onObjectTreeCreated);
    console.log('ExternalTreeExtension has been loaded.');
    return true;
  }

  async unload() {
    this.viewer.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, this._onObjectTreeCreated);
    console.log('ExternalTreeExtension has been unloaded.');
    return true;
  }

  onModelLoaded(model) {
    model.getObjectTree(function (tree) {
      let ext = viewer.getExtension('ExternalTreeExtension');
      ext.tree = tree;
      ext.initTree();
    });
    
  }

  createTreeNode(id, text, children = false) {
    return { id:id, text:text, children:children};
  }

  async initTree(){
    const tree = new InspireTree({
      data: async (node) => {
        let ext = viewer.getExtension('ExternalTreeExtension');
        if (!node || !node.id) {
          let rootId = ext.tree.getRootId();
          let hasChild = ext.tree.getChildCount(rootId) > 0;
          let newNode = ext.createTreeNode(rootId, 'model', hasChild);
          return [newNode];         
        } else {
          ext.tree.enumNodeChildren(node.id, (childId) => {
            let nodeName = ext.tree.getNodeName(childId);
            let hasChild = ext.tree.getChildCount(childId) > 0;
            let newNode = ext.createTreeNode(childId, nodeName, hasChild);
            node.addChild(newNode);
          }, false);
        }
        return [];
      }
    });
    tree.on('node.click', function (event, node) {
        event.preventTreeDefault();
        viewer.isolate(node.id);
        viewer.fitToView(node.id);
    });
    let ext = viewer.getExtension('ExternalTreeExtension');
    return new InspireTreeDOM(tree, { target: ext.treeContainer });
  }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('ExternalTreeExtension', ExternalTreeExtension);

